# If I turn into a Gas Spore and use Death Burst, do the other spores count as "me"?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, skills, homebrew

In [Circle of the Seedling](https://dnd-5e-homebrew.tumblr.com/image/133953037260) you can use Wild Shape to turn into plants. If I am a [Gas Spore](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17147-gas-spore) and use Death Burst, assuming the target fails the save and eventually dies from the infection, are the resulting Gas Spores that grow from their corpse considered my character?

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no precedent for this in any other part of the game system. We are definitely in DM ruling territory.

However, I would say these are no more your character than if the story involved you creating progeny any other way. The only difference is the speed in which this is possible. The new gas spores are your character's "children". Sadly they are mindless, highly dangerous, monstrous children, and are unlikely to recognise or respect their relationship to your character as their parent.

Probably the only useful thing they would do is ignore the druid if he/she was currently transformed into something that they could not infect, such as another gas spore.

Comment: I see, I can see this being DM territory. If you look at an answer to another question I asked recently, someone made the case that I would die if I used Death Burst as I would BE the spores and could not reform. But if I explode INTO the spores and those spores infect someone and grow into Gas Spores then those would still be made out of me. I guess I'm just making an argument that would have to be approved by my DM...

Comment: @Hunter: Yes I also answered that question. These are fun things to consider, but you do probably want to avoid too weird outcomes, because the game moves away from anything the rules can say about it. My ruling would be that you don't "become the spores" any more than you become the blood of a wolf form that was injured, or a fire that a fire elemental set before dying.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Plant Wild Shape refers to and modifies the rules for the general druid feature Wild Shape, which says (PHB 66):

> You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die.

The Gas Spore's Death Burst ability says:

> The gas spore explodes when it drops to 0 hit points.

Since both rules are triggered by you dropping to 0 hit points in your Gas Spore form, it would be the DM's call as to whether you revert without exploding, or whether you explode, possibly infecting other creatures, and then revert.

But in either case, your reverted natural form is you.

The [July 2016 Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-july-2016) says that a druid in Wild Shape reduced to 0 hit points by a Disintegrate spell turns to dust.  This seems to imply a druid must have some sort of body to revert from.  If the DM ruled you did explode, it's still the DM's call whether a cloud of spores is "enough of a body" to revert from, but this precedent does lean much more toward suggesting you wouldn't reform after all.  So maybe being a Gas Spore was a poor idea.  Unless your character's friends can get a True Resurrection, time to play a different character.

Any spores that grow from an infected corpse are really the offspring of the spore that exploded anyway, not the same spore, which is quite dead.  There are other ways for a character to become a parent, if your DM allows, and there's no reason for your offspring in those situations to be considered you.

Of course, the DM can also specifically permit you to switch to playing as a different creature, related to your original PC or not.

Comment: I can see this as being a solid answer. But since those spores are made of your body, and it's your body that you're transforming, I can see those spores as being "you", part of your form. After all that's why you die, because you explode into those spores. They'd still be your body imo. I think I'll just have to ask my DM. As a counter to it, I could see the argument that if all creatures in that radius succeed on the save, you just die instead without reverting.

Comment: While I understand where you are coming from with the answer, I would say that, while Disintegration reduces a target to pure, inert dust, the Gas Spores are not dust but living cells, and the spores have the ability to rapidly grow into a new being. It isn't too much of a stretch to say that the spores condense on a surface and rapidly grow back into a Mushroom, which then reverts to being a Druid.

Comment: Xanathar introduced a rule that order of things that happened simultaneously is decided by the person who controls the character that has his round at the moment. Thus, it might or might not be the DM. Also, Sage Advice was charged since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 3):

### No

When you revert to your own form, the shapechanged form vanishes. So when you explode and revert there would be no spores left over that could spawn into anything, as they were part of your shapechanged form.

All the spore fragments dissolve and you magically reconstitute into a single, whole body. You certainly would not want to remain in exploded state: apart from being inconsistent with damage done to the shapechanged form vanishing when you revert, it would spell instant death to your character.

I am mostly writing to provide an update on [schleper's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115763/if-i-turn-into-a-gas-spore-and-use-death-burst-do-the-other-spores-count-as-me/115769#115769). There are additional, optional rules from *Xanathars Guide to Everything* on simultaneous effect, on p. 77

> In rare cases, effects can happen at the same time, especially at the
> start or end of a creature's turn. If two or more things happen at the same time on a character or monster's turn , the person at the game table - whether player or DM- who controls that creature decides the order in
> which those things happen.

Based on this, only if you died during your turn, (say due to an opportunity attack) you could determine the order, and decide that you explode first, and revert second.

The Sage Advice ruling on disintegrate also has been reverted. It now reads:

> **What happens if a druid using Wild Shape is reduced to 0 hit points by disintegrate? Does the druid simply leave beast form?** The druid leaves beast form. As usual any leftover damage then applies to the druid’s normal hit points. If the leftover damage leaves the druid with 0 hit
> points, the druid is disintegrated.

(The older SA ruling said, you are disintegrated in your shapechanged form). This new ruling would support that any effect that renders you unconscious, puts you to 0 hits or kills your wildshape form just makes you revert to your normal form first, and then applies remaining effects.